# How to change the background color in semantic ui react?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I just started developing with react semantic ui, I used the Homepage layout available on react.semantic-ui.com but I want to change the dark grey color on the top portion and footer but I am unable to find anything in semantic ui css

[image]

[image]

Comment: To start back-traceing styling: open your [devtool inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) (`ctrl+shift+c` in Chrome) and click on the element to open the "Elements" tab (highlighting the element) and the "Styles" sidebar (showing the relevent CSS) to find where the background-color is coming from. Then look either for the class - or if's under `element.style` then it's being applied by a `style` tag on the element itself.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be coming from the file [`semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/09e2ccd59d9407055f78e78d53fca7d71cbc6e1e/dist/components/segment.min.css), a minified copy of [semantic.css](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/09e2ccd59d9407055f78e78d53fca7d71cbc6e1e/dist/components/segment.css#L675):

```
.ui.inverted.segment,
.ui.primary.inverted.segment {
    background: #1B1C1D;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

which is build from [`segment.less`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/383871090cda527df916e1751279b3de79b07480/src/definitions/elements/segment.less#L650):

```
.ui.inverted.segment,
.ui.primary.inverted.segment {
    background: @invertedBackground;
    color: @invertedTextColor;
}
```

---

As to how that files being included in your project - there appear to be a few ways:

> Installing Semantic UI React provides the JavaScript for your components. You'll also need to include a stylesheet to provide the styling for your components.

from their [Usage guide](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/a2cc3a7996e667b2870e9fc6ecdccfbae1949f96/docs/src/views/Usage.js). Just search for something like `semantic.min.css` in your repo.